# JS Как отформатировать 12345.00 в 123.45 (до сотых)?

Tags: javascript

Простите за нубство, не знал, как загуглить, гугл выдаёт только "сокращение до сотых из 12345.000123 до 12345.00". 
Собсно вопрос в заголовке, буду благодарен за быстрый ответ

Comment: В чем проблема разделить на 100 и использовать код из гугла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = 12345.000123;
var b = a.toFixed(2);
var c = (a / 100).toFixed(2);
var d = Math.floor(a / 100).toFixed(2);
console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вы почитали вопрос?)
 Мне такой результат выдаёт гугл, он мне не нужен) Я специально его описал)
Как сделать из 12345.00 - 123.00

Comment: о, изменённый код, ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо!